# Best practices: ExoPlayer that gets passed between activities/fragments/adapters?

Tags: android, android-videoview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-video-player

I have a fairly complicated use case. I'm not looking for specific code, but more high-level technical help about how to best approach this situation.

Here is how I would like my app to work:

- The main page of my app is a `RecyclerView` where each item has a video. Only one video should play at a time as the user scrolls down (the first fully visible one).
- Tapping on a video in the `RecyclerView` takes you to a second page where I want to continue playing the video where it left off on the first page.
- When going back from the second page to the first page, the video should continue playing where it left off on the second page.
- I have several other pages where I would also like to play a video/videos.

From my readings, for performance reasons, it sounds like I should only be creating one instance of `ExoPlayer` and passing it around.

So my question is, what is the best approach to handling a situation where I should only be creating one instance of `ExoPlayer`, and then be able to pass it between activities, fragments, adapters, etc.?

Should I create a `Singleton` where I handle all video player logic and pass that between pages as needed? Or should I go with a different approach?

Comment: ExoPlayer is a library, more so than a class. For video playback, you will use a custom view from the ExoPlayer library, such as `PlayerView`. That view is owned by an activity and cannot be passed between activities. So, you need to design this core portion of your UI to be a single activity, using fragments/composables/whatever for the individual screens or other UI elements.

Comment: @CommonsWare My current architecture is to use multiple activities with multiple fragments. It would be a big job to move to a single-activity architecture. What other options might I have?

Comment: None, pretty much. Note that I am not implying that the entire app has to be a single activity, just the portion that has this hero transition from an element in a scrolling list to the second page. Basically, everything that has to share a playing video needs to be in one activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just want to make it clear, in case it wasn't in my post, that this isn't pertaining to transitions/animations, but rather keeping one instance of ExoPlayer and passing it around (ignoring animations). You mentioned "hero transitions", so that confused me a bit. Does your answer remain the same?

Comment: I am not aware that ExoPlayer is capable of seamlessly having one `PlayerView` play a video, then have a separate `PlayerView` pick up from where the first one left off, without rebuffering, re-downloading (if playback is of a stream), etc.. I cannot rule that out, of course. If I were implementing this, I would be aiming to have a single `PlayerView` that handles playback, and that the rest of the UI adapts around it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Would it be possible to have a single `PlayerView` and pass that around without rebuffering/redownloading/etc?

Comment: Within a single activity, yes. That is why I mentioned hero transitions, because it sounds an awful lot like that is what you are aiming for from a user experience, even if you do not necessarily need the animation aspect. But you cannot share a single `PlayerView` between separate activities.

Answer (score 0):

One option that you would have, instead of creating a singleton with all the problems that it may bring, it's to implement dependency injection (easier with HILT, instead of pure dagger) and you in the end create a single instance of the exoplayer object, but your activities don't depend on another class but get injected with the dependency.

Also, you could consider creating a small fragment in charge of playing the video, and this gets injected the exoplayer instance. That way you will only have that logic to play video only once, even if you recreate this fragment several times for all your screens.